# __attribute__((packed)) and __attribute__((__packed__))

Tags: gcc, struct, attributes, packed

is there a difference between 
`__attribute__((__packed__))` and 
`__attribute__((packed))`?

And if a struct is packed like this: 
`struct test { int a; short b; } __attribute__((__packed__))` there is never a need to use the packed attribute on each of the members of the struct, because when the struct is packed, all members are always packed, too. Is this correct?

Comment: `__packed__` works even if you have a `#define packed` somewhere, otherwise they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, both are equal. The leading and trialing `__` of a keyword are optional, so you can use your attribute in headers, *"without being concerned about a possible macro of the same name."*

**Source:**

- [GCC Manual - 6.36 Specifying Attributes of Variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)
- [GCC Manual - 6.31 Attribute Syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax)